# System Restore takes up more space as time goes by

Tags: windows-7, disk-space, system-restore

Does anyone know the reason for System Restore taking up more drive space after only a few days? I'm not making any new restore points but it still seems to increase in size.

For example, I make a restore point that's like 600 MB in size; when I check back in a few days, the used disk space from restore points has increased to 25 GB.

What is going on here? I'm running Windows 7 Home Premium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your seeing is space being taken up by both "Restore Points" *and* "Previous Versions" of files - both of which are stored in the same folder.

"Previous Version" file copies get made regularly by default in Win7.

Comment: What files actually get get backed up to previous versions? Is it really enough to use 30 GBs of disk space after only a few days?

Comment: The Previous Versions affect practically every file/folder on the hard drives.  Go right click a folder and select "Restore Previous Versions" and you'll see what shadows exist for that folder.  The Previous version get cleaned up as you need the space, so they're not a big deal.  My Win 7 system has about 30GB of space (12% of each drive) being used right now as well. Previous Versions has saved my butt a few times, it's worth it. ;)

Comment: Perhaps I'll just keep system restore using 15% of my drive again. Now that I understand how useful previous versions can be. Thanks for the explanation it was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have automatic updates on?

Windows automatically creates restore points before updates are applied incase of failure (Which is good - Windows 7 is **VERY** good at recovering from failures).

After this, most installations now also create automatic restore points.

If this is a problem, you can look in `Control Panel > System Properties` (<kbd>Windows Flag</kbd>+<kbd>Pause/Break</kbd>), then click `System protection` on the left. Click the `Configure` button and you can manually control the space usage.

Comment: I don't have automatic updates on and usually when I check CCleaner for new system restore points after Windows Update and other installations I don't find any new restore points.

Comment: Then how do you know it is system  restore taking up the space... Where are you seeing this? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Well I check System Restore > Configure in system properties and view the used disk space. It just magically increases for some reason. I also tend to check my hard drive a lot and my free space decreases. When I comes to disk space I'm always looking for ways to free up used space.